# Write names of files in a folder that have been created/modified today to text file

Tags: vbscript

I have written a VBScript to write all the file names in a folder to a text file, but what I actually want is a listing of only the names of .txt files in a specific folder that have been modified or created today.

The code:

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjOutFile
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("D:\test")
Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\test\File_names.txt")
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name)
Next

ObjOutFile.Close
```

Comment: the .txt files in a folder with currentdate

Comment: You want a text file full of all the names of .txt files in a specific folder that have a modified or created date of today? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a long time since I have written any VBScript but this is along the right lines.  You may need to adjust it a bit

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjOutFile
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("c:\temp\")
Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\File_names.txt")
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
   If (LCase(Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))) = ".txt") Then
    If FormatDateTime(ObjFile.DateLastModified, 2) = FormatDateTime(Now(), 2) OR FormatDateTime(ObjFile.DateCreated , 2) = FormatDateTime(Now(), 2)   Then
            ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name)
    Else
            ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & " - Modified:" & FormatDateTime(ObjFile.DateLastModified, 2) & " " & FormatDateTime(Now(),2) & " Created: " & FormatDateTime(ObjFile.DateCreated , 2) & " " & FormatDateTime(Now(), 2) )

    End if
   Else
     ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & " Not Text")
   End if
Next
ObjOutFile.Close
```

Comment: it was really helpfull . Thanks :) . But i need to get all the file names with modified or current date with today alone no need of time . Could you please help in this. Your script picks oly the latest file name with recent time. Actually I have 10 files for today date but script picks oly 2 file names which has the latest time

Comment: @Monica  `CreatedDate` added.  I have just run this and it picked up all file with a created or modified date of today regardless of time.  If this doesn't work for you can you post a same of the files with their created and modified dates please (screenshot)

Comment: attached the files in folder. can u loook into it.

Comment: Script s picking oly first 2 file names

Comment: @Monica  If you take my updated code and run it, it should output a file that will have extra info for each file it thinks doesn't match.  Try it and post a sample of the result if its not obvious what the problem is.

Comment: output is lke this temp_test.txt - Modified:4/25/2015 5/21/2015 Created: 4/25/2015 5/21/2015 . this file has been modified and creadted on 4/25/2015. But I need file name which are modified and creadted on currentdate

Comment: When you say current date do you mean today?

Comment: yes it means today. In my screenshot if u see there are many files which has the date of 5/21/2015(currentdate). I need the script to pick all the file names with currentdate and write into a file

Comment: So run that script I have posted and post an entry of a file that is missing from the first script I posted.  I.E An entry in the file that has extra info after the name when you don't think it should.  What is that date in your screen shot? Create?  Modified?  Last Accessed?

Comment: In screen shot it refers to the modified date. From the script which was posted earlier the result is only first 2 file names are wrriten. but I have many files with the same modified date and these file names are not written

Comment: Yes I know what you want and the first script I posted should do that (it does for me).  You say it isn't so I am trying to help you find out why.

Comment: In screen shot it refers to the modified date. From the script which was posted earlier the result is only first 2 file names are wrriten. but I have many files with the same modified date and these file names are not written

Comment: I know all of that, you have repeated the same thing over and over.  Why are only 2 filenames being written?

Comment: Actually I dont no vbscript. Thats why I get confused why it picks oly 2 files names alone

Comment: And that is why I posted the code with the extra debug info.  The file that gets created now will have all you need to tell why its not working as you expected.  Hence why I asked you to post lines from that file. Not the 2 that  were in the file, at least one that wasn't but should be

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet with changes only:

```
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    If StrComp( Right( ObjFile.name, 4), ".txt", vbTextCompare) = 0 and _
      ( Fix( ObjFile.DateCreated)      = Fix( Now) or _
        Fix( ObjFile.DateLastModified) = Fix( Now)       ) Then

            ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name)
    End If 
Next
```

[`FIX()` explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/eric-s-complete-guide-to-vt-date.aspx):

> date format is a floating point value, counting days since midnight 30
>   December 1899. Hours and minutes are represented as fractional days